# Database to support offline access to 5000 x 5000 matrix of integers in Swift iOS

Tags: database, ios, gis

My app needs offline access to GIS information using a database table approximately 5000 columns by 5000 rows. I would be able to access a single value by using a 'horizontal' and 'vertical' value key pair (i.e. latitude, longitude) and resolving those values into a single entry from the database, in this case a simple unsigned integer.

For example, if you were looking at a physical printed map, and I said the grid location was 'A4' you would point to that grid location on the map and tell me the entry value '327'.

In my mind it is just a large spreadsheet with the row headers being latitude from 0 .. n and column headers showing longitude 0 .. n. In this database, I would need to be able to interpolate decimal numbers to a column-row 'location'.

Can I accomplish the above with CoreData? Or SQLite? Are there other technologies available?

Comment: Please see [Are questions about software technologies acceptable?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2451/185)

Comment: Aw geez. I got booted over here from SO :) I guess I'll just figure it out some other way. Thanks

Comment: As you see I didn't put your question "on hold" – I just meant you might need to slightly adjust it. You are looking for software, aren't you? A database for iOS on mobile with a fitting library to integrate it with your app? It's really just wording IMHO. Plus maybe some details, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)